# gradle fails with "could not create jna native library" jndispatch.dll

Tags: windows, gradle

Just downloaded the latest gradle 1.12 release in zip and unzipped it. (c:\dev)
When I'm trying to run it using

```
c:\dev\gradle-1.12\bin>gradle
```

I get a FAILURE:

```
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  Could not create JNA native library 'C:\projects\gradle_lib\native\jna\win32-x86\jnidispatch.dll'.
```

I have had gradle working before on a different machine, so there may be some hidden settings in my home or secondary home directory polluting my gradle install, but I seriously doubt that. Apart from that I never put anything in c:\projects.

I'm on gradle-1.12, java 1.7.0_55, windows 7 enterprise SP 1.

I don't think the build.gradle is of any importance but I was trying to follow the [spring.boot authentication example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)

Just downloaded version 1.10 which has worked before for me, but is also giving same trouble.

The complete stack trace with debug enabled:

```
gradle --debug build
12:57:54.089 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.services.NativeServices] Unable to initialize native-platform. Failure: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Failed to load native library 'native-platform.dll' for Windows 7 x86.
caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
12:57:54.118 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:57:54.120 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:57:54.120 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:57:54.121 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:57:54.121 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not create JNA native library 'C:\projects\gradle_lib\native\jna\win32-x86\jnidispatch.dll'.
12:57:54.176 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:57:54.180 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
12:57:54.190 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.NativeIntegrationException: Could not create JNA native library 'C:\projects\gradle_lib\native\jna\win32-x86\jnidispatch.dll'.
12:57:54.191 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.jna.JnaBootPathConfigurer.configure(JnaBootPathConfigurer.java:61)
12:57:54.193 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.services.NativeServices.initialize(NativeServices.java:67)
12:57:54.193 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.logging.internal.ConsoleConfigureAction.execute(ConsoleConfigureAction.java:30)
12:57:54.193 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.logging.internal.ConsoleConfigureAction.execute(ConsoleConfigureAction.java:27)
12:57:54.193 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.logging.internal.OutputEventRenderer.attachConsole(OutputEventRenderer.java:68)
12:57:54.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingManager.attachConsole(DefaultLoggingManager.java:146)
12:57:54.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:168)
12:57:54.194 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
12:57:54.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
12:57:54.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
12:57:54.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
12:57:54.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
12:57:54.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
12:57:54.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
12:57:54.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
12:57:54.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
12:57:54.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\projects\gradle_lib\native\jna\win32-x86\jnidispatch.dll (The system cannot find the path specified)
12:57:54.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.jna.JnaBootPathConfigurer.configure(JnaBootPathConfigurer.java:51)
12:57:54.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 15 more
12:57:54.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Answer (score 0):

my environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` was pointing to `c:\projects\gradle_lib`

Answer (score 0):

strangely my antivirus detected jndispatch.dll file as unclean.
with this it also detected adb and avd files as unclean and dumped them to its vault.

i had to restore them from AVG vault.
configure AVG to ignore (add folder to exception list) folder of AndroidStudio and other required folder.

if you are without antivirus and still facing this problem, remember that windows 7 and above have inbuilt 'windows defender'. see whether this fellow is doing the same thing. put your folder in antivirus 'exclusion' list as the vendor is trusted world wide.

this same answer would go to '[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26355645/2173890)'. i didn't had enough reputation to answer this question there and there.